# Find two factors of a number, which are similar or close to each other

Tags: factors

given a number `x`, how can I find two numbers `y` and `z`, such that `x = y * z` and either `y==Z` or `y` and `z` are close to each other? Also `x`,`y`,`z` are `Integers`.

**Example:**

```
x = 16484, y=z=128;   x=4096, y=z=4096;  x=8192, y=64, z=128
```

Comment: Did you try anything by yourself?

Comment: I could not come up with a generic solution other then bruteforce

Comment: Google for "Fermat factoring". Fermat came up with something significantly better than brute force a few hundred years ago.

Comment: I guess this is why he was Fermat :)

Comment: Assuming 16484 is a typo, do you only need it for powers of 2?

Comment: Henrik2: Unfortunately, it is not the case. I need it for arbitrary numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
for (int i=sqrt(x); i>=1; --i)
{
    if ( x % i == 0 )
    {
        cout << " y = " << i << endl;
        cout << " z = " << x / i << endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

Will this serve the purpose? Can you think of any test case where this may be invalid?

Comment: More correct, simpler and faster solution than mine. Well done.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is to use prime factorization and then sort the list and multiple each other value to y and the rest to z. You should then have the two factors which are as close as possible to each other. There may be a more effective way to do this but I can not think of one right now.

Example of programming prime factorization:
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-prime-factors-of-a-given-number/

Example: x = 24, 24 = 2 * 2 * 2 * 3, y = 2 * 2 and z = 2 * 3. So x = y(4)*z(6) = 24

Edit:
I realized that this will not work since if you have the numbers 2,2,731 the correct values for z and y would be 4 and 731, not 2 and 1462 which my solution would give. Maybe someone can give a suggestion on how to solve this.

Edit2:
Not sure if correct but you could sort them by largest prime first and then take the two largest primes into y and z. Then each following prime will be multiplied into the smallest value of y or z. I am not sure if this solution works 100% of the time but I tried a few cases on paper and it seems good enough. Tested it between 2 and 1 000 000 and this method was true for those values.